# I have a problem with react and Visual Studio Code when save

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When save in visual studio code using React it breaks everything

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mHG9.png)

Comment: Does your file have `.tsx` extension?

Comment: nop! Is a index.js. 
The file .tsx works good

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Does it work now properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS Code determines file's language by its extension. In your case, it is `javascript`, but should be `javascriptreact`.

Either:
- change all file extensions from `.js` to `.jsx`,
- or configure file association settings in your user/workspace settings:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed JS-CSS-HTML Formatter plug-in effects in your VSCODE, try to remove uninstall it or disable it. Then restart your VSCODE. That's all.

Comment: This did help thx

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix is to press on the bottom right side of the screen where it says "JavaScript", a drop-down menu will be opened, type "rea" for "JavaScript React" and press enter.

It works only for the current file, not even for other files in the same project. for a permanent fix, try one of the other answers.

here is how VS Code documentation explains it:

> **Changing the language for the selected file** -
> In VS Code, we default the language support for a file based on its filename extension. However, at times you may want to change language modes, to do this click on the language indicator - which is located on the right hand of the Status Bar. This will bring up the *Select Language Mode* dropdown where you can select another language for the current file.

> Tip: You can get the same dropdown by running the Change Language Mode command (Ctrl+K M).

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview

[image: I highlighted the button]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I think that isn't an error, rather it's a warning of `prettier`, because by default `prettier` in VSC requires an empty line at the end of your code.

Right click -> Format document